# Jinja 2 - Filter Optimization (Datetime Formatter)

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using Jinja 2 filter in a flask web application.
The Jinja filter does the following:

1. Convert datetime according to the user's time zone.
2. Format the date according to the user's time zone.

The things here that the user's time zone is saved in the DB.
And since this filter being called dozens of times by each user when he loads some pages in my app, the DB is being queried dozens of times as well.

How can I reduce the number of queries to DB within this filter?
Can I query the user's time zone only one time and save it as a global variable in Flask somehow?

The Code:

```
# set jinja2 filter - convert utc to user's tz and format the time
def datetimefilter(value):
    try:
        # query user's time zone
        try:
            tz = pytz.timezone(db.session.query(Users.user_tz).filter(Users.id == session['_user_id']).first()[0])
        # else set utc
        except Exception as e:
            tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')

        # query user's country
        try:
            country = pytz.timezone(db.session.query(Users.country).filter(Users.id == session['_user_id']).first()[0])
        except Exception as e:
            country = None

        # set format according to country
        if str(country) in ['United States', 'US', 'USA']:
            format = "%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M"
        else:
            format = "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M"

        # convert time zone and format time
        utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
        tz_aware_dt = utc.localize(value)
        local_dt = tz_aware_dt.astimezone(tz)
        return local_dt.strftime(format)

    except Exception as e:
        return value

# create filter
app.jinja_env.filters['datetimefilter'] = datetimefilter
```

Comment: You can reduce it by 1/2 if you get tz and country from db at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch the country and timezone once in your route handling function, and pass them to the template as variables.

Jinja2 [custom filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#custom-filters) can accept multiple arguments in addition to the value being filtered, so pass these variables to the filter.

Here's a simple example

```
import datetime as dt

from jinja2 import Environment
import pytz


def datetimefilter(value, tz, country):
    try:

        # set format according to country
        if str(country) in ['United States', 'US', 'USA']:
            format = "%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M"
        else:
            format = "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M"

        # convert time zone and format time
        utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
        tz_aware_dt = utc.localize(value)
        local_dt = tz_aware_dt.astimezone(tz)
        return local_dt.strftime(format)

    except Exception:
        return value


# Create and register the filter and template
env = Environment()
env.filters['datetimefilter'] = datetimefilter
template = env.from_string("It's {{ now | datetimefilter(tz, country) }}!")

user_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
user_country = 'US'
rendered = template.render(now=dt.datetime.now(), tz=user_tz, country=user_country)
print(rendered)
```

Result:

```
It's 12/19/2020, 05:35!
```